# What is the best way to regsiter a user with ASP.NET Identity but store other relevant info in another table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to have customers register with my application using ASP.NET MVC 5 website using ASP.NET Identity but I also want to have a separate customer table which would store personal information such as first name, last name, phone etc.  How would I best accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: I guess it depends what else you are doing.

For example if you are using Entity Framework code first, then you could choose to add these additional columns to the Users class/table which is one of the (I believe) 6 tables Identity wants out of the box. Run migrations and you're done. However, my preference might be to keep all default Identity stuff in its own context or separate tables, then have a separate `Profiles` table (that may well map directly to `Users` in the `Identity` context). Have you done the tutorials and got stuck at a certain specific stage?

Comment: The latter part is what I would like to do.  I was not referring to an example as this is an actual project I am working on.  Could you direct me to the tutorial you mentioned?  Thanks